# Changing hostname (with hostnamectl) in chroot environment does not work (Iso customization) Ask

Tags: chroot, hostname

I can not change the hostname in the chroot environment (Ubuntu) I tried hostnamectl set-hostname but it says:

Failed to create bus connection: Couldnt find file or folder

Then I tried changing it with hostname and edited the /etc/hostname file and put my name in it. Thought it worked but when I burned the finished remastered .iso on a stick and bootet from it, it didnt work.

Somebody know a solution?

Comment: What method are you using to remaster the iso?

Comment: Hey, I used this method http://www.gtkdb.de/index_34_1259.html and it all worked. I just cant change the hostname permanently it seems or I am doing something wrong